# rake or any other rake command not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Hi i was doing some coding and tried to

```
rake routes
```

and this error message came up out and i dont know what to do

```
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 10.4.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.4.0. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.

/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in `block in setup'
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler.rb:121:in `setup'
/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/simplybel/projects/gamification/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/simplybel/projects/gamification/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/simplybel/projects/gamification/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/home/simplybel/projects/gamification/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/simplybel/projects/gamification/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/simplybel/projects/gamification/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

any help with this would really be appreciated

Comment: I had that problem and prepending `bundle exec` didn't fix it for me.

Comment: @GitaarLAB the error message actually is not that helpful. rake is not in the gem file si you can't just go update the version. And pre-pending bundle exec to everything is not the greatest solution.

Answer (score 27):

I got this problem on an old project after running the command `rails new MyNewProject`

To fix it on the old project I just went into the Gemfile.lock file and searched for `rake`. The I found `rake (10.3.2)` and replaced it with `rake (10.4.2)` and that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 20):

You generally shouldn't manually edit `gemfile.lock`. And if you do delete the file and restart from scratch make sure the versions of you gems in your `gemfile` are specified so you'll get the ones back that you expect. For this situation:

`$ bundle update rake`

worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

This error is because your gem file is using a different version of rake, so you need to specify which of the rake versions you need, so this can help you

```
 bundle exec rake routes
```

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this issue today. I used RubyMine to build a new project and it installed rake 10.4.2. For my work I have to use 10.3.2 for db:migrate.

RubyMine solution:
To fix the problem in RubyMine I opened opened up the run configuration for db:migrate, went to the Bundler tab and checked "Run the script in context of the bundle (bundle exec)"

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use older version just remove newer version:

```
gem uninstall rake --version=<newer version>
```

In your case:

```
gem uninstall rake --version=10.4.2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the older version of the gem by using :

`gem uninstall rake --version=[Here version that you want to delete]`

After uninstall just use `rake routes` normally.

Answer (score 2):

1. manually delete you gemfile.lock file
2. run bundle install

That fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to update your gemfile.lock and change the version of rake from 10.4.0 to 10.4.2 an you can continue working as you were before this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
bundle exec rake routes
```

makes it work, but it's way better if you pick the right version of **rake** needed and change it in your **Gemfile.lock**

Answer (score -1):

There were two answers for me:

1. Temporary solution:

`bundle exec rake routes`

2. Permanent Solution

`gem update rake`
and then `rake routes`

Comment: I didn't do the downvote here, just to clarify.  And at first I was going to comment, "why the downvote when the more focused update is safer?" but then I noticed that it suggests "gem update rake" rather than "bundle update rake".  The likely issue is that the system is ahead of an old project's bundle.  So the "bundle update [rake]" is what's required.  And "bundle update rake" does only what's needed, whereas "bundle update" is likely to trigger other issues and make more work.  Of course a broad update is a good idea from time to time, but it should be a calculated decision.

Comment: This is the exact solution in my case with the exact problem. So it is still the best answer for me. Sorry if not worked for you guys.

Comment: @elc First of all, thanks for clearing that. Bizarre thing is; "bundle update rake" didn't solved my case but "gem update rake" did. I've read the answers from top to bottom on this question and tried other answer from some other questions on the portal. Finally, "gem update rake" was the answer for me. I don't know the logic behind. Maybe  the "downvoter" could tell us.